# mdadm copy superblock from drive to drive

Tags: mdadm, raid5, openmediavault

i have an RAID5 consisting of 7 HDDS. One Drive is only partially accessable anymore.
Unfortunatly i used the create command which resetted the superblocks of the 6 healthy drives.
is there a way to access a superblock backup, save it to a file and write this file to each hdd. there was a website stating that there are several superblock backups through the disk. the raid was created via openmediavault.